# currentView in ContainerView goes away when parent view changes

Tags: ember.js

this is example http://jsfiddle.net/EugeneVB/yhNzm/1/
When i go to tab2, then return to tab1, ContainerView is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your fiddle, the tab1 template refers to `{{view Em.ContainerView currentViewBinding="view.controller.cv"}}`

Here `view.controller.cv` (which btw could be just used as `cv` here) refers to a view you manually instantiate during App.Tab1Controller init() method. This controller is only instantiated once, during application initialization.

I think Ember.js is constantly tracking potential leaks, so here when you switch from tab1 to tab2, the tab1View is destroyed, and all of its subwiews too. (and consequently, its `currentView`.
As it is a bound (remember Ember.js bindings are two way bindings), the "view.controller.cv" is also ddestroyed.

Comment: I've did new example with one way binding, http://jsfiddle.net/EugeneVB/yhNzm/10/, but without success

Comment: Oh, i understand, one way binding doesn't help because view is destroyed, i should create new view.

Comment: Yes, but I think creating a view manually like this seems quite a bad smell. If you find a solution, please tell me, otherwise I hope I have the time to implement it.

Comment: I do this
`MyContainerView = Em.ContainerView.extend({
    currentViewClass:null,
    currentViewClassObserver:function() {
        this.set('currentView',this.currentViewClass.create());
    }.observes('currentViewClass'),
    didInsertElement:function() {
        this.currentViewNameObserver();
    }
});`

Comment: Hum, I think I would go further with the outlets concept, and use it in the tab1Content: see http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/yhNzm/14/

Comment: Outlets is great solutions, and I use it instead ContainerView.
But in this case I should use ContainerView in CollectionView.
I have list of views, and each view has ContainerView.

Comment: I can't figure your complete case, but if you provide a jsfiddle, I could take a look.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/EugeneVB/yhNzm/16/
I tried to do example, but it's imposible to do simple example with clear sense. It works, i don't know why.
I can't spend your time more, thank you very much.